"using" keyword equivalent in Dart/Flutter
Is there like a "using" keyword equivalent for Dart? I would like to simply close a database connection whenever an exception occurs. If there isn't is there like a logic to base of? So that I can implement it in my code, in case there is no "using" equivalent keyword in Dart
I tried searching for using equivalent for Dart, but I found nothing.

No there isn't an equivalent feature in dart, but it has been suggested to add such a feature to dart (https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/2051), you are free to comment on or upvote the proposal if you support it.

What db manager or package are you using currently? Maybe trying with sqflite or drift for relational DBs or Hive for non-relational would help for now.

HI @mmcdon20. Is there like a logic or algorithm to implement a "using"

Hi @AlainC.Jiménez i am using the postgres package

@GianCarloGallano if you read through the comments in the above link, there are suggestions on how you might implement using without needing a new language feature.

@GianCarloGallano You can also just declare your resources before a try-catch-finally and close the resources in the finally section.

BTW, "using" can mean different things in different languages (and sometimes the concept uses a different keyword; e.g. with in Python), so you should clarify which language you're coming from (C#?).

I am using Dart language @jamesdlin.

@GianCarloGallano There is no using keyword in the Dart language.  Clearly you mean something like "What is the Dart equivalent of using from C#?".  It's important for readers to understand which language uses the keyword you're asking about.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

I followed the comment of mmcdon20 to declare the resources before the try catch block, with minor adjustments.
// create late variable
late Connection DbConn;
try {
  DbConn = createDbConnection();
  // sql query, and such

  // close connection
  DbConn.close();
} catch (e, s) {
  // some code
} finally {
  // close connection if it remains open (like when exception occurs)
  if (DbConn.isOpen) DbConn.close();
}


You don't need the late keyword here.

Also the finally will run regardless of if an exception occurs or not, so you can remove the DbConn.close() from the end of the try, and in finally simply do DbConn.close(); without the if condition.

Thank you for spotting the redundancy @mmcdon20. The late keyword just ensures that the DbConn variable is initialized in all parts of the code.

If you remove late then you get a compile time error if it is uninitialized before you use it. But with late you only get an error at runtime if it is uninitialized. It is less safe to use late not more safe.

What if createDbConnection() already throws an error? Then the finally block will crash, because DbConn is not initialized.

I don't like using the late keyword. It's better to use nullable variables, at least the IDE warns you.

@CsabaGergely you're right, I missed that it should be a Connection? DbConn;. You can do DbConn?.close(); in finally.
